# Push Notification stopped on switch to Zendesk Messaging from Zendesk classic chat to Chatbot

Tags: chatbot, zendesk, zendesk-app

I switch from the classic chat widget to Messaging Chatbot everything is ok but the Desktop and push notifications stopped working is there any provision to enable the push notification on the Zendesk chatbot or not I did not find it anywhere.

Chat Notification Working on Classic Chat Widget like this: https://prnt.sc/geNGL7ZAiqcL

On Messaging Chatbot I am not getting such notifications with Sound effects so how can

So my query is
**Can we have such a notification for Messaging Chatbot or not?**

Regards